# How do I Base64Encode a TImage in FMX application

Tags: delphi, encoding, base64, firemonkey, rad-studio

I need a simple way to encode the TBitmap of TImage into a base64 encoded representation for sending via JSON format.  I don't want to make use of Indy libraries, instead I want to use what is built into current Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following which is working, it returns the base64encoded string which I add as a string pair to a TJSONObject.

```
//use NetEncoding
function GetBase64EncodedImage(Bitmap: TBitmap): String;
var
  InputStream : TMemoryStream;
  OutputStream : TMemoryStream;
  StringList: TStringList;
begin
  InputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  OutputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //Save image to stream
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(InputStream);
    InputStream.Position := 0;
    //Encode the stream
    TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode( InputStream, OutputStream );
    OutputStream.Position := 0;
    StringList.LoadFromStream(OutputStream);
    Result := StringList.Text;
  finally
    InputStream.Free;
    OutputStream.Free;
    StringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm aware there may be a way to eliminate the TStringList, so a helpful addition or code change here to get the Stream straight to String would be good instead of having to load it to the TStringList for the result may be better.

**Edited**
Below the refactored version as per @remy's suggestion

```
var
  InputStream : TMemoryStream;
  OutputStream : TStringStream;
  StringList: TStringList;
begin
  InputStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  OutputStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    //Save image to stream
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(InputStream);
    InputStream.Position := 0;
    //Encode the stream
    TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode( InputStream, OutputStream );
    OutputStream.Position := 0;

    Result := OutputStream.DataString;
  finally
    InputStream.Free;
    OutputStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: To eliminate the TStringList`, use `TStringStream` instead of `TMemoryStream` for the output. You can then return the `TStringStream.DataString` value

Answer (score -1):

you can uses this function for encode

uses unit :

```
uses System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.NetEncoding;
```

code :

```
function EncodeFile(FFileLocation : String) : String;
begin
  if not FileExists(FFileLocation) then begin
    ShowMessage('File Not Exist');
    Exit;
  end;

  var Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  var StreamOutput := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.LoadFromFile(FFileLocation);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(Stream, StreamOutput);
    Result := StreamOutput.DataString;
  finally
    Stream.DisposeOf;
    StreamOutput.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

and this for Decode

```
procedure DecodeFile(FData : String; out FStream : TMemoryStream);
begin
  var Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  var SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Text := FData;
    SL.SaveToStream(Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0;

    TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(Stream, FStream);
    FStream.Position := 0;
  finally
    SL.DisposeOf;
    Stream.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: This is used to encode files from your directory. If you want to use it, you can do it like this
var Base64String := EncodeFile('D:/folder1/image.jpg');

Comment: Encoding the TBitmap of a TImage is not encoding a file.  The question would of read "How do I encode a File ...."